# Datapicker with option select a few single days

Tags: javascript, php, datapicker

I need calendar with option select a few single days.
For example:

```
2016-02-19
2016-02-20
2016-02-24
2016-04-15
```

I looking like solutions, but I found nothing.
All datapicker provides opportunities like date of 2016-02-19 date to 2016-02-23 . But I need option to select single day.

Comment: there are many date picker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/   or http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML or https://plugins.jquery.com/ui.datepicker/ or http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

Comment: thanks, i see this page but i need datepicker with option select a few single days.

Comment: you mean date-range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) have an option to select [multiple dates](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#multidate), which I have used myself.

Comment: so easy... hehh... thank u so much!